# Bash "touch" not working with variable name

Tags: linux, bash

I've connected via SSH to a server, and have a script which is called in parallel, as such I want to name output files by seconds since epoch. However, this code is not producing any files whatsoever.

EDIT: This following code has been edited a number of times thanks to assistance in the comments. It is currently not working, and reduced to a MWE. Directories are modified below to remove server information.

```
#!/bin/bash

error() {
    echo "`TZ=UTC date`: $0: error: $@"
    exit 1
}

EXE="tblupcpp.R"
FIXED_PARAMS=""

CONFIG_ID=$1
INSTANCE_ID=$2
SEED=$3
INSTANCE=$4
shift 4 || error "Not enough parameters"
CONFIG_PARAMS=$*
TIME=$(date +%s)
STDOUT="out${TIME}"
STDERR="err${TIME}"

Rscript x/tblupcpp.r ${CONFIG_PARAMS} 1> ${STDOUT} 2> ${STDERR}
```

Relevant output after running:

```
Wed Mar  4 20:09:16 UTC 2020: x/tuning/target-runner: error: out1583352531.txt: No such file or directory
```

I've checked both the /x/ and the /x/tuning/ directories for any files created, there are none.

Comment: Have you tried putting these five lines in a separate file and running it directly by itself to see if it's a problem with this code or with something else in your script/invocation?

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` will show the commands as they're executing, which can provide hints if there are hidden characters. Otherwise, some of the possible issues include the working directory not being what you expect leading to the files being located in the wrong directory (or not created at all if there aren't permissions).

Comment: I put these lines in a separate script and ran it, it works fine. Must be something else with the script.

Comment: ("too long to be created before being edited"? Not sure what that means. `touch` won't return until the filesystem has already committed that it's going to present the file as existing to any other running process on the system; it's not guaranteed it'll survive a reboot, but it's guaranteed to show up as existing to every other running program on the system).

Comment: Show your shebang.

Comment: I just tested it separately - works fine, @thatotherguy. Weird. Sure, I'll edit the question with the rest of the script.

Comment: What we want is a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible program* that reproduces the problem when run without changes. Since this doesn't reproduce the problem, it doesn't meet the definition; but just dumping all your code in won't meet the definition either, because it wouldn't be *shortest possible* code.

Comment: Also -- please run your program through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it identifies. Among other things, `params=$*` is innately, unfixably broken, because it has no way to distinguish between `yourprogram "argument 1" ` and `yourprogram "argument" "1"`. Always use arrays, not strings, to hold lists of things.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use `touch` here at all in the first place. `someprogram >"$stdout"` will create the file named in the variable `stdout` itself.

Comment: Use of lowercase variable names above is deliberate; see POSIX guidelines at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, specifying that all-caps names are to be used for variables that can modify behavior of the shell and other POSIX-specified utilities, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on behavior of POSIX-specified tools; read that keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable with a name that overlaps a preexisting environment variable will overwrite the latter.

Comment: (For more on the above "arrays, not strings" argument and the side effects that can be caused by not following it, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your assistance. This script is based on an example provided in the R irace package, as such, much of it is inherited from the published script, including variable naming (personally I come from a Java background so it's all alien to me). Additionally the usage of ``params=$*`` is inherited. I am about to update the question with additional information I've discovered with your assistance.

Comment: If your script's absolute path is `/x/foo.r`, and you refer to it as `x/foo.r` (with no leading `/`) in the script's text, then the command can be expected to fail unless you put in a `cd /` to ensure that the *current working directory* is just above `x`, which you're referring to via a relative path. That said, having permission to create files in `/` is both unusual and ill-advised. (Of course, it seems more than a little likely that you've oversimplified your directory names and such is not in fact the case).

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest adding the line `set -x` early in your script to enable trace-level logging.

Comment: I could also conceive of getting that error message if your code's current working directory doesn't exist. (That's perfectly possible on UNIX; `tempdir=$(mktemp -d); cd "$tempdir"; rm -rf "$tempdir"` and you're in precisely that situation). Which is to say: One of the avenues you should follow in debugging on is determining what the *current working directory* of your script is at runtime.

Comment: Yes I simplified the directory paths for ease of reading & security. Added `set -x` as recommended, I just read up on it - didn't realise this was an option, good tip! I'll look into directories, this script is working in two, both /x/ and /x/tuning (simplified).

Comment: In a strange turn of events, the adding of `set -x` at the top caused the files to begin saving. There are now 6 files named `out[timeSinceEpoch]` and `err[timeSinceEpoch`. I commented the `set -x` line and tried running again, no files generated. Any idea why the trace is allowing the files to save (most are empty, a couple have unrelated errors from the Rscript)?

Comment: That's... very unusual. Frankly, I'd probably pull out sysdig for further debugging, but it's not ideal from the perspective of accessibility to beginners.